# People Picker:’ Select People and Groups’ finder doesn’t find users from site collection

Tags: 2007, people-picker, user-accounts

Environments(test/production):

Production:
•   MOSS 2007 Ent. SP2 (2008 r2 x64)

•   1x App(2008 r2 x64)

•   2x WFE(2008 r2 x64)

•   1x SQL 2008 (2008 r2 x64)

•   Profile import will find users and import is successful every time

Test:

•   MOSS 2007 Ent. SP2 (2003 r2 x64)

•   1x App(2003 r2 x64)

•   2x WFE(2003 r2 x64)

•   1x SQL 2005 (2003 r2 x64)

•   Profile import will find users and import is successful every time

Problem:

‘Select People and Groups’ finder cannot find any users who are not visited on the site. Only when user is visited and contributed some action on the site then user(s) can be found in the ‘Select People and Groups’ finder (Site Setting people picker)

[image: People findert]

Our test environment will find users who are not visited on the site if the fresh user`s profile is import to the MOSS SSP.

This problem should not be even Active Directory Related…

**Is there any solution or workaround for this problem?**

I can provide more information about the environments if it would help...

thx in advance

UPDATE: Installing latest MOSS 2007 CU did the trick and all are well. Thanks for your answers

Comment: Sounds like SharePoint can't contact Active Directory?

Comment: People picker will find users with NT-name... that query will contact AD...?

Answer (score 3):

Copying the original poster's answer so we can mark this answered:

> Installing latest MOSS 2007 CU did the trick and all are well. Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

(sorry I can't ask this in a comment because I'm new)

Does your test environment include the builtin group Authenticated users, or maybe Domain users (actually any group where all users are a potential member) ?

Comment: Do you mean "NT authenticated users" in some sharepoint related group?

Comment: in fact, if your users are defined in the site, not directly but included in a NT group, I think SP is able to "expand" the groups to find users.

Comment: they are added as NT Groups in the site not one by one...

Answer (score 0):

a few questions:

- How do you and the other users authenticate to MOSS (NTML, FBA, etc...)
- Do the users that you can't find via people picker, have been granted access to the site collection?

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Auth method: NTLM
Users have been granted access and related users profiles are imported successful in to the MOSS SSP.

Comment: Could it be firewall problem or some sort of ?